# No permission to use getFileById in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have following problem.

I have two files:

1. Source file - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15zIdIeYFlca-SQ0ryl89oX_tbGjO_6cipqHkkxog7ho/edit#gid=0
2. Target file - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gGExeO2x8pqNzTPRvel8p-wwe-BDkdF5c6BFA8j_Py0/edit#gid=0

In the source file there is a script (function is named onEdit triggered with onEdit event). When you change the value of R3 cell (Source File) to other "Advisor" whole row should be copied to target file, but sometimes it works, sometimes not. If you change the value of advisor field once and it works try couple of times more and for sure there will be a problem with permission in a while.

When it's not working I get msg that there is problem with permission of executing function called getFileById, which is used in following line:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1gGExeO2x8pqNzTPRvel8p-wwe-BDkdF5c6BFA8j_Py0');
```

Any ideas what to do to solve the problem and why sometimes it works fine ?

Comment: Do modify other files you need to create a google Project.... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project Follow those...

Answer (score 0):

Scripts using a 'simple' trigger can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other files because that would require authorization.

[See here to learn more about the restrictions on simple triggers.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started)

Comment: right is no way to do this¿
seems super obvious you want to populate a template from a form.... a way to give the same trigger to a form an a doc maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure you have all the permissions following the next steps:

1. Open the script project. At the left, click Project Settings
2. Select the Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor checkbox.
3. At the left, click Editor <>.
4. At the left, click the appsscript.json file.
5. Locate the top-level field labeled oauthScopes. If it's not present, you can add it.
6. The oauthScopes field specifies an array of strings. To set the scopes your project
   uses, replace the contents of this array with the scopes you want it to use. For
   example:

   `{"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"], }`

Retrieved from: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes